# Using LGPL 2.1 in a closed-source project

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I'm making a commercial closed-source project in C++. I use [this](https://github.com/BYVoid/uchardet/blob/master/COPYING) library, uchardet, which is licensed under MPL 1.1 or GPL 2.0 or LGPL 2.1.

For say LGPL 2.1, can I statically link uchardet to MY project with no modifications to uchardet, without disclosing my projects source code?

If so, what else do I have to do?

Comment: Also, see: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic

Comment: thanks! that helps. It looks like the answer is yes, I have to release some object code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like with the post provided by @Nikos C., LGPL 2.1 requires the object code to be published.

I just decided to get rid of this hassle and use a different library.